# Trigger inserting a second row when updating the same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, duplicates

Table `TMSEMP` stores basic employees details. Table `CHANGES` is to log changes to this table.

The trigger below is on `TMSEMP` to write these changes when `CHANGEFLAG` is set to Y.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [XUSER].[Update_Changes Table] 
ON [XUSER].[TMSEMP]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

declare @empref as varchar(10)
declare @date1 as Datetime
declare @changeflag as varchar (10)
declare @firstnames as varchar(20)

set @empref = (select empref from inserted)
set @date1=(select getdate())
set @changeflag =(select changeflag from inserted )
set @firstnames = (select firstnames from inserted)

if @changeflag='Y'
begin

-- INSERT INTO CHANGES TABLE
insert into XUSER.CHANGES (empref,autokey,changedate,changefield,newvalue) 
select @empref, (select max(autokey)+1 from XUSER.changes),@date1,'FIRSTNAMES',@firstnames 

--RESET CHANGEFLAG BACK TO N
update XUSER.tmsemp set changeflag='N' where empref=@empref

end
```

The problem I have is that 2 records are being written to CHANGES.

If I remove the below

```
--RESET CHANGEFLAG BACK TO N
    update XUSER.tmsemp set changeflag='N' where empref=@empref
```

1 entry is correctly posted --> However the field remains as Y but needs to be N.

How can I stop the record being posted twice.

```
AUTOKEY CHANGEFIELD CHANGEDATE  NEWVALUE
9   FIRSTNAMES  2020-01-09 20:51:02.493 Shane5
10  FIRSTNAMES  2020-01-09 20:51:02.607 Shane5
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Thanks - What do you mean here - Is the "if @changeflag='Y'" statement not doing this?

Comment: Thanks Marc_s - I'm not sure where I'd start to rewrite any different? The only problem arises when the update CHANGEFLAG is set to N

Answer (score 0):

You have created After Insert and After Update trigger, Please remove the high lighted **update** key word.

[image: and]

Comment: Thanks - However when I remove "Update" the trigger doesn't fire. I guess the 3rd party software that is writing to TMSEMP uses an Update Statement?

Comment: What do mean by trigger does not fire? If you are creating Insert trigger, it should After Insert only.

Comment: What I mean is - nothing happens - ie nothing writes through to the CHANGES table. I need to have After Update in order for this to happen